# Photoshop ScriptUI: Show a dialog window, close it, show it again gives an empty full size window

Tags: javascript, dialog, photoshop, extendscript, adobe-scriptui

In my script for Photoshop CC 2015 (Windows 10), written in JavaScript, I am processing all layers of the active document in a loop and want to show a setup dialog in each step.

For simplification, take the following working example. The window is defined outside the loop, and among other steps which are stripped here, the window is shown once every step in the loop:

```
#target photoshop

var w = new Window('dialog', 'Title');
var b = w.add('button', undefined, 'OK');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // other code
    w.show();
    // other code
}
```

When you execute it, a small dialog window with just one "OK" button appears, as expected. You can close it using the "OK" button. **But every consecutive `w.show()` produces a blank window that almost fills the entire screen, with no controls whatsoever.** It can only be closed using the ESC key.

I tried overriding the `b.onClick` event and manually call `close()`, but that did not change anything.

Upon inspection of the `w` variable, it is obvious that the `bounds`, respectively `location` and `size` somehow got changed. I tried resetting these values to their previous state, and the window size is restored. However, the button is still not visible.

Am I missing something? How can I get the dialog window to show up correctly more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code, it works for me with Photoshop CC + OSX.

`w.close()` destroy dialog window, so you should create again.

press a button named 'ok', press return key are same as `w.close()`.

```js
#target 'photoshop'

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var w = W();
  $.writeln(w.show());
}

function W () {
  var w = new Window('dialog', 'Title');
  var b = w.add('button', undefined, 'OK', {name:'ok'});
  return w
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I did not know that `close()` destroys the window.

Comment: Actually I did not find any hint to this in the official manuals or other sources. This should be added...